# Eclipse: Dot acts as wildcard in "open resource" filter on *nix

Tags: eclipse

I've noticed on my Mac and Linux machines that when I use Eclipse's "Open Resource" feature (ctrl-shift-R), when I enter a resource name, Eclipse treats "." as a wildcard.  So, for example, if I typed "Account.java", Eclipse would list every file beginning with account, followed by java - AccountManager.java, AccountDao.java and so on.  Is there a way to change it on Mac and Linux to behave more like I am expecting from Windows?  On Windows, the dot isn't treated as a wildcard and only Account.java would be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Open Resource filter is prefix based. So when you type "Account.java" it is actually "Account*.java*". To prevent prefix matching you need to type < or space character, e.g "Account<.java".

See [Eclipse Open Resource docs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-dialog-open-resource.htm).

Cheers,
Max

Comment: I understand that Open Resource is prefix based in the sense that entering "account" would display any resource beginning with "account" but I didn't see anything in the documentation you sent that would suggest "Account.java" would be expanded to "Account*.java".  And I can say for a fact that the behavior differs by platform.  On Windows, Account.java would bring back only files beginning with Account.java.  I'm curious why there is a difference and how to get Eclipse on Linux/Mac to behave like it does on Windows.